# I have a formula component to assign Regions depending on country input of a lead. However, the formula is too long. Is there a workaround?

Tags: formula, formula-field, territory-management, recordtriggeredflow, multi-regional

The requirement is to automate choosing regions, subregions, and theaters with the country input. We want this for reporting leads based on regions which is not offered by Territory Management feature of Salesforce. I've included the formula component that I've tried with flows down below. It is too long. I also tried to break it to different formulas and include them in different "update record" pieces but its messy and doesn't work as expected. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
CASE (
[Lead].Country,
"United States", "NAM",
"Canada", "NAM",

"Anguilla", "LATAM",
"Antigua and Barbuda", "LATAM",
"Argentina", "LATAM",
"Aruba", "LATAM",
"Bahamas", "LATAM",
"Barbados", "LATAM",
"Belize", "LATAM",
"Bermuda", "LATAM",
"Bolivia", "LATAM",
"Brazil", "LATAM",
"British Virgin Islands", "LATAM",
"Caribbean Netherlands", "LATAM",
"Cayman Islands", "LATAM",
"Chile", "LATAM",
"Colombia", "LATAM",
"Costa Rica", "LATAM",
"Cuba", "LATAM",
"Curaçao", "LATAM",
"Dominica", "LATAM",
"Dominican Republic", "LATAM",
"Ecuador", "LATAM",
"El Salvador", "LATAM",
"Falkland Islands (Islas Malvinas)", "LATAM",
"French Guiana", "LATAM",
"Grenada", "LATAM",
"Guadeloupe", "LATAM",
"Guatemala", "LATAM",
"Guyana", "LATAM",
"Haiti", "LATAM",
"Honduras", "LATAM",
"Jamaica", "LATAM",
"Martinique", "LATAM",
"Mexico", "LATAM",
"Montserrat", "LATAM",
"Nicaragua", "LATAM",
"Panama", "LATAM",
"Paraguay", "LATAM",
"Peru", "LATAM",
"Puerto Rico", "LATAM",
"Saint Barthélemy", "LATAM",
"Saint Kitts and Nevis", "LATAM",
"Saint Lucia", "LATAM",
"Saint Martin", "LATAM",
"Saint Pierre and Miquelon", "LATAM",
"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "LATAM",
"Saint-Martin", "LATAM",
"Sint Maarten", "LATAM",
"Suriname", "LATAM",
"The Bahamas", "LATAM",
"Trinidad and Tobago", "LATAM",
"Turks and Caicos Islands", "LATAM",
"U.S. Virgin Islands", "LATAM",
"Uruguay", "LATAM",
"Venezuela", "LATAM",

"Afghanistan", "EMEA",
"Africa", "EMEA",
"Albania", "EMEA",
"Algeria", "EMEA",
"Andorra", "EMEA",
"Angola", "EMEA",
"Armenia", "EMEA",
"Austria", "EMEA",
"Azerbaijan", "EMEA",
"Bahrain", "EMEA",
"Belarus", "EMEA",
"Belgium", "EMEA",
"Benin", "EMEA",
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "EMEA",
"Botswana", "EMEA",
"Bulgaria", "EMEA",
"Burkina Faso", "EMEA",
"Burundi", "EMEA",
"Cameroon", "EMEA",
"Cape Verde", "EMEA",
"Central African Republic", "EMEA",
"Chad", "EMEA",
"Comoros", "EMEA",
"Congo", "EMEA",
"Croatia", "EMEA",
"Cyprus", "EMEA",
"Czech Republic", "EMEA",
"Denmark", "EMEA",
"Djibouti", "EMEA",
"Egypt", "EMEA",
"Equatorial Guinea", "EMEA",
"Eritrea", "EMEA",
"Estonia", "EMEA",
"Ethiopia", "EMEA",
"Faroe Islands", "EMEA",
"Finland", "EMEA",
"France", "EMEA",
"Gabon", "EMEA",
"Gambia", "EMEA",
"Georgia", "EMEA",
"Germany", "EMEA",
"Ghana", "EMEA",
"Gibraltar", "EMEA",
"Greece", "EMEA",
"Greenland", "EMEA",
"Guinea", "EMEA",
"Guinea-Bissau", "EMEA",
"Hungary", "EMEA",
"Iceland", "EMEA",
"Iran", "EMEA",
"Iraq", "EMEA",
"Ireland", "EMEA",
"Isle of Man", "EMEA",
"Israel", "EMEA",
"Italy", "EMEA",
"Ivory Coast", "EMEA",
"Jordan", "EMEA",
"Kazakhstan", "EMEA",
"Kenya", "EMEA",
"Kosovo", "EMEA",
"KSA", "EMEA",
"Kuwait", "EMEA",
"Latvia", "EMEA",
"Lebanon", "EMEA",
"Lesotho", "EMEA",
"Liberia", "EMEA",
"Libya", "EMEA",
"Liechenstein", "EMEA",
"Lithuania", "EMEA",
"Luxembourg", "EMEA",
"Madagascar", "EMEA",
"Malawi", "EMEA",
"Mali", "EMEA",
"Malta", "EMEA",
"Mauritania", "EMEA",
"Mauritius", "EMEA",
"Mayotte", "EMEA",
"Moldova", "EMEA",
"Monaco", "EMEA",
"Montenegro", "EMEA",
"Morocco", "EMEA",
"Mozambique", "EMEA",
"Namibia", "EMEA",
"Netherlands", "EMEA",
"Niger", "EMEA",
"Nigeria", "EMEA",
"North Macedonia", "EMEA",
"Northern Ireland", "EMEA",
"Norway", "EMEA",
"Oman", "EMEA",
"Pakistan", "EMEA",
"Palestine", "EMEA",
"Poland", "EMEA",
"Portugal", "EMEA",
"Qatar", "EMEA",
"Reunion", "EMEA",
"Romania", "EMEA",
"Russia", "EMEA",
"Rwanda", "EMEA",
"Saint Helena", "EMEA",
"San Marino", "EMEA",
"Sao Tome and Principe", "EMEA",
"Saudi Arabia", "EMEA",
"Senegal", "EMEA",
"Serbia", "EMEA",
"Seychelles", "EMEA",
"Sierra Leone", "EMEA",
"Slovakia", "EMEA",
"Slovenia", "EMEA",
"Somalia", "EMEA",
"South Sudan", "EMEA",
"Spain", "EMEA",
"Sudan", "EMEA",
"Swaziland", "EMEA",
"Sweden", "EMEA",
"Switzerland", "EMEA",
"Syria", "EMEA",
"Tajikistan", "EMEA",
"Tanzania", "EMEA",
"Togo", "EMEA",
"Tunisia", "EMEA",
"Turkey", "EMEA",
"Turkmenistan", "EMEA",
"UAE", "EMEA",
"Uganda", "EMEA",
"Ukraine", "EMEA",
"United Arab Emirates", "EMEA",
"United Kingdom", "EMEA",
"Uzbekistan", "EMEA",
"Vatican City", "EMEA",
"Western Sahara", "EMEA",
"Yemen", "EMEA",
"Zambia", "EMEA",
"Zimbabwe", "EMEA"

"American Samoa", "APJ",
"Australia", "APJ",
"Bangladesh", "APJ",
"Bhutan", "APJ",
"British Indian Ocean Territory", "APJ",
"Brunei Darussalam", "APJ",
"Cambodia", "APJ",
"China", "APJ",
"Christmas Island", "APJ",
"Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "APJ",
"Cook Islands", "APJ",
"East Timor", "APJ",
"Fiji", "APJ",
"French Polynesia", "APJ",
"Georgia", "APJ",
"Guam", "APJ",
"Hong Kong", "APJ",
"India", "APJ",
"Indonesia", "APJ",
"Japan", "APJ",
"Kiribati", "APJ",
"Kyrgyzstan", "APJ",
"Laos", "APJ",
"Macao, Special Administrative Region of", "APJ",
"Malaysia", "APJ",
"Maldives", "APJ",
"Marshall Islands", "APJ",
"Micronesia, Federated States of", "APJ",
"Mongolia", "APJ",
"Myanmar", "APJ",
"Nauru", "APJ",
"Nepal", "APJ",
"New Caledonia", "APJ",
"New Zealand", "APJ",
"Niue", "APJ",
"Norfolk Island", "APJ",
"North Korea", "APJ",
"Northern Mariana Islands", "APJ",
"Palau", "APJ",
"Pakistan", "APJ",
"Papua New Guinea", "APJ",
"Philippines", "APJ",
"Pitcairn Islands", "APJ",
"Russian Federation", "APJ",
"Samoa", "APJ",
"Singapore", "APJ",
"Solomon Islands", "APJ",
"South Korea", "APJ",
"Sri Lanka", "APJ",
"Taiwan", "APJ",
"Thailand", "APJ",
"Tokelau", "APJ",
"Tonga", "APJ",
"Tuvalu", "APJ",
"Vanuatu", "APJ",
"Vietnam", "APJ",
"Wallis and Futuna Islands", "APJ"

"ROW"
)
```

Comment: so, for formulas, you _might_ squeak by using the CONTAINS solution in [Account Management formula examples](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.useful_advanced_formulas_acct_mgmt.htm&type=5)  but personally, I'd store all this in custom metadata and then use a before save flow to set a Text field value. You can also eliminate places like `Pitcairn Islands` as < 100 people live there and I doubt you're doing business there.

Comment: Thanks for the help @cropredy. I ended up creating a flow with decision components that have boolean formulas. It is working as expected now.

Comment: You should add an Answer with your solution to benefit the rest of the Community

Comment: I ended up creating a flow with a lot of formulas to assign these. Basically all decision trees are tied to formulas and divides into branches where I assign correct theaters, regions, and subregions.

Comment: Emir - please create an answer, not a comment; then 48 hours later you can accept your answer and thus the community will know there's a solution